# Create a bookmark in master/detail flow

Tags: android, android-fragments

I made a simple master/detail app, populated my fragments with different data, created my layouts and everything works fine. What is the best way to add a "bookmark" button that will store whatever fragment you tapped the button on, to be recalled in, for example, another list view with only the bookmarked fragments accessible?

Answer (score 0):

Understanding your problem right you have a List and a Detail View with some more information about your selected Element. Then tapping the *bookmark* button you want to save it(=the content of the selected Fragment) somehow.

- layout: use a [Floating Action Button](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#) which bookmarks the selected Fragment
- code: assuming you're using a database create a table with your bookmarks; having none, simply create a new one

Comment: Thanks for your response! I see it needs further clarification: basically you are right, except that I am not looking to save the contents of the fragment, but rather to simply have another list view called bookmarks, that is empty when you install the app, and get's populated with only the links to the fragments you would bookmarked.

The app is basically a book, and my fragments are chapters in the book, while in the list view I got names of the chapters. User would be able to bookmark favorite ones and access them from a bookmark tab (hope that makes sense).

Comment: A good approach would be doing as i said before then creating a BookmarkListFragment that uses a [Cursor Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html), populating your bookmark table